# How to update a dynamic table?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Before you see the code, I want to try and explain what I want to happen. This is a personal project, not worried about sql injection, nothing production, etc., etc..

My application lets a user create an account, select which classes they've taken, then views them.

**What I have currently:** A user creates a username/password that is stored in a Users table. The username is also stored as a global variable. At the same time, a copy of the master course list (107 rows) is made and renamed as the users username (from the global variable.) After creating the username/password, the user is brought to a form where they select courses they've taken and their corresponding grade.

**Where I'm stuck:** The user can select which courses they've taken and choose their corresponding grade. The users table is made on the fly so I don't know any other way to access the table during run time besides using Dynamic SQL. I just want to update the user table with their selection during run-time.

[image: Example of user selection.]

From here, my code basically says "If check marked, update users course table with their grade and status where course# = x." Is my issue the global variable? Should I use my Users table somehow? Should I use QUOTENAME in some way instead of UPDATE? My code with @sql keeps coming up with syntax errors so I feel like a simple fix could do the trick.

```
private void btnNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (checkIntrotoPublicSpeaking.Checked || checkEffectiveOralCommunication.Checked || checkProfComm.Checked)
        {
            List<SqlParameter> sqlOralComm = new List<SqlParameter>();
            sqlOralComm.Add(new SqlParameter("Username", GlobalVariables.username));
            sqlOralComm.Add(new SqlParameter("IntrotoPublicSpeaking", cboxIntrotoPublicSpeaking.Text));
            sqlOralComm.Add(new SqlParameter("EffectiveOralCommunication", cboxEffectiveOralCommunication.Text));
            sqlOralComm.Add(new SqlParameter("ProfComm", cboxProfComm.Text));
            DAL.ExecSP("CreateOralComm", sqlOralComm);
        }
}
```

and

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[CreateOralComm]
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @Username nvarchar(30),
    @IntrotoPublicSpeaking nvarchar(3),
    @EffectiveOralCommunication nvarchar(3),
    @ProfComm nvarchar(3)
AS
BEGIN
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

-- Insert statements for procedure here

    DECLARE @sql as nvarchar(max)
    SET @sql = 'UPDATE ' + @Username + ' SET Grade = ' + 
    @IntrotoPublicSpeaking + ', Status = ''Completed'' WHERE Course = 
    7600105'
    EXEC sp_executesql @sql;

    /*
    SELECT QUOTENAME(@Username) 
    SET Grade = 'A', Status = 'Completed' 
    WHERE Course = 7600105;
    */
END
GO
```

I feel like a nuisance. I know I'm not that good and there's probably A LOT of easier ways to go about this but I'm really trying my best to get through this with the knowledge I have.

Comment: the main issue seems to be the dynamic sql inside the stored procedure. this foils your otherwise flawless attempt to be safe for scripting, and is probably not necessary. You'd just write the update command directly into the procedure source code. look up the proper syntax! it would be something like `UPDATE tablename SET Grade=@IntrotoPublicSpeaking WHERE username=@Username`

Comment: In the "SET @sql..." line. After I hit the next button, an exception is thrown where it says System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Incorrect syntax near ','.'

So I'm assuming it's somewhere by Status but I'm almost 100% sure I have that syntax right...

Comment: you're emitting something like `UPDATE tryingtotryhard SET Grade...`. tsql would expect a name of a table or a table alias where you inject the user name. look up the possible `UPDATE` syntax for sql server, it is either `UPDATE table SET assignments WHERE conditions` or `UPDATE alias SET assignments FROM tablename alias WHERE conditions`.

Comment: @dlatikay but if I make the table at run-time, how will I know the "tablename"?

Comment: @dlatikay thank you, going to look into that right now.

Comment: there should be no valid reason to create a table at runtime in your scenario. where, how, and why are you doing that?

Comment: You create a new table for every user? Why?

Comment: @dlatikay I... I don't know, I thought that would be best... SQL is a pretty bad area for me...

Comment: @AaronBertrand I... I don't know, I thought that would be best... SQL is a pretty bad area for me...

Comment: Don't take this the wrong way, but fixing this syntax isn't going to solve the problem; I think you're going to need help beyond the scope of this site. At a high level, we use *a table* to group similar things. Think about Amazon, surely you don't think they add a new table to their database every time they have a new book to sell?